# Listing intervals with the most overlaps

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table like:

```
create table movement_logs (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  room_id integer NOT NULL,
  entry_time timestamp NOT NULL,
  exit_time timestamp,
  user_id integer NOT NULL
)
```

This models a domain where users enter rooms. This table logs timestamps when users enter and leave rooms.

I want query for the time windows where most users were in a room. I am using Postgres. Can this be done in SQL?

Comment: I'm not sure about your question. ¿Are you asking for example for the row that have more overlapping rows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible in SQL.
See example.

```
--test data
create table movement_logs (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  room_id integer NOT NULL,
  entry_time timestamp NOT NULL,
  exit_time timestamp,
  user_id integer NOT NULL
);
insert into movement_logs values
 (1,10,'2023-09-15 10:00:00','2023-09-15 11:00:00',1001)
,(2,10,'2023-09-15 10:20:00','2023-09-15 11:20:00',1002)
,(3,10,'2023-09-15 10:20:00','2023-09-15 11:21:00',1003)
,(4,10,'2023-09-15 11:10:00','2023-09-15 11:21:00',1001)
,(5,20,'2023-09-15 12:20:00','2023-09-15 12:21:00',1001)
,(6,10,'2023-09-15 12:20:00','2023-09-15 12:21:00',1005)
;
-- query
select room_id,event_time
     -- cumulative sum of events by time
  ,sum(qty)over(partition by room_id order by event_time) qty
from(-- group events by time - count of events in this time
  select room_id,event_time,sum(inout) qty
  from( -- all events in log entry=+1 exit=-1
    select room_id,entry_time event_time, 1 inout
    from movement_logs
    union all
    select room_id,exit_time event_time, -1 inout
    from movement_logs
   )x
 group by room_id,event_time
)y
order by room_id,event_time
```

Query result

| room_id | event_time | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2023-09-15 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 10 | 2023-09-15 10:20:00 | 3 |
| 10 | 2023-09-15 11:00:00 | 2 |
| 10 | 2023-09-15 11:10:00 | 3 |
| 10 | 2023-09-15 11:20:00 | 2 |
| 10 | 2023-09-15 11:21:00 | 0 |
| 10 | 2023-09-15 12:20:00 | 1 |
| 10 | 2023-09-15 12:21:00 | 0 |
| 20 | 2023-09-15 12:20:00 | 1 |
| 20 | 2023-09-15 12:21:00 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach would be the usage of the [range data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN), tsrange. When you have an entry time and exit time, this would be beneficial to your data model and application because of the potential constraints, operators and indexes you could use.

```
CREATE TABLE movement_logs
(
    id              INTEGER NOT NULL,
    room_id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    entry_exit_time TSRANGE NOT NULL,
    user_id         INTEGER NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO movement_logs
VALUES (1, 10, TSRANGE('2023-09-15 10:00:00', '2023-09-15 11:00:00'), 1001)
     , (2, 10, TSRANGE('2023-09-15 10:20:00', '2023-09-15 11:20:00'), 1002)
     , (3, 10, TSRANGE('2023-09-15 10:20:00', '2023-09-15 11:21:00'), 1003)
     , (4, 10, TSRANGE('2023-09-15 11:10:00', '2023-09-15 11:21:00'), 1001)
     , (5, 20, TSRANGE('2023-09-15 12:20:00', '2023-09-15 12:21:00'), 1001)
     , (6, 10, TSRANGE('2023-09-15 12:20:00', '2023-09-15 12:21:00'), 1005)
;

SELECT room_id
     , s::TIMESTAMP
     , COUNT(user_id)
FROM movement_logs
         RIGHT JOIN GENERATE_SERIES('2023-09-15 10:00' -- start
                        , '2023-09-15 13:00' -- end
                        , INTERVAL '15 minutes') g(s)
                    ON entry_exit_time && TSRANGE(s::TIMESTAMP, (s + INTERVAL '15 minutes')::TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 2;
```

The function tsrange() makes the ranges for you, and could leave the lower or upper range NULL. The [operator &&](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) looks for overlapping ranges and generate_series() creates the different time windows you want to measure. In this example I use an interval of 15 minutes, you could change this to some other value.